# Simple loop for all elements of an etree object?

Tags: python, lxml

I've got a function to return a list from an etree element, but it doesn't look through nested elements.

```
<elem>
    <variable id="getthis">
        <!-- / -->
    </variable>
    <if>
        <variable id="alsoGetThis">
            <!-- Keep looping through all elements -->
        </variable>
    </if>
</elem>
```

(I'm working with [Valid XML](http://pastebin.com/vRRxfWiA))

So currently the variable within the `<if>` is ignored, so how can you loop through all levels of the tree? I'm assuming this is a simple task, but maybe I'm wrong. (I'm new to Python & don't always think like a programmer)

Python func to get the variables:

```
def collect_vars(self, elem):
    elemVars = []
    if elem.tag == 'variable':
        elemVars.append(elem.attrib['id'])
    elif e in elem == 'variable': # don't want to be doing these
        elemVars.append(e.attrib['id'])
    return elemVars
```

So all I want to end up with is the list `elemVars` containing all the variable IDs within the given `<elem>`

Comment: Your questions needs to be more specific. What do you want to get?

Comment: I just want to go through a each level of the xml element, I'll add some XML to explain. apologies.

Comment: That's not valid XML. Try to give a [short, self contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I know, its an example. The full, valid, XML is here; http://pastebin.com/vRRxfWiA (nice website btw!!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that you are not visiting all nodes in the file. You are only visiting the children of the `elem` element, but you are not visiting the children of these elements. To illustrate this, running the following (I have edited your XML to be valid):

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree as etree

xml_string = """<elem>
    <variable id="getthis" />
    <if>
        <variable id="alsoGetThis" />
    </if>
    </elem>"""

e = etree.fromstring(xml_string)

for node in e:
    print node
```

results in

```
<Element variable at 7f53fbdf1cb0>
<Element if at 7f53fbdf1cf8>
```

So you are not visiting the child `variable` of the node `if`. You will need to *recursively* visit each node in your XML file, i.e. you function `collect_vars` will need to call itself. I'll post some code in a bit to illustrate this.

**Edit:** As promised, some code to get all `id` attributes from your element tree. Rather than using an accumulator as Niek de Klein has I have used a generator. This has a number of advantages. For example, this returns the `id`s one at a time, so you can stop processing at any point, if, for example, a certain `id` is encountered, which saves reading the entire XML file.

```
def get_attrs(element, tag, attr):
    """Return attribute `attr` of `tag` child elements of `element`."""

    # If an element has any cildren (nested elements) loop through them:
    if len(element):
         for node in element:
            # Recursively call this function, yielding each result:
            for attribute in get_attrs(node, tag, attr):
                yield attribute

    # Otherwise, check if element is of type `tag` with attribute `attr`, if so
    # yield the value of that attribute.
    if element.tag == 'variable':
        if attr in element.attrib:
            yield element.attrib[attr]

ids = [id for id in get_attrs(e, 'variable', 'id')]

print ids
```

This *yields* the result

```
 ['getthis', 'alsoGetThis']
```

Comment: Thank You. I thought that was the approach I needed, I just can't get it written. The full script is here; http://pastebin.com/D9DkQdEv

Comment: Yes, thats spot on. Thanks I've been reading about yield but not actually used it yet.

Comment: No problem. I don't use `yield` very much but it can be quite useful. It is particularly useful for working with long lists and files where you wouldn't want to read the whole thing into memory.

Comment: Basically perfect for what I'm doing here then I guess! :D

Answer (score 4):

Consider learning [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) and using the `xpath` member of LXML. Let's say your XML tree is called `t`, as if you'd issued

```
>>> s = """<elem>
    <variable id="getthis">
        <!-- / -->
    </variable>
    <if>
        <variable id="alsoGetThis">
            <!-- Keep looping through all elements -->
        </variable>
    </if>
</elem>
"""
>>> t = etree.fromstring(s)
```

Then you can find all elements in the tree with

```
>>> t.xpath("//*")
[<Element elem at 0x2809b40>, <Element variable at 0x2809be0>, <Element if at 0x2809af0>, <Element variable at 0x2809c80>]
```

and all `variable` elements with

```
>>> t.xpath("//variable")
[<Element variable at 0x2809be0>, <Element variable at 0x2809c80>]
```

`xpath` returns a list of elements satisfying the XPath condition you specify, represented as element trees:

```
>>> [x.attrib["id"] for x in t.xpath("//variable")]
['getthis', 'alsoGetThis']
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to put XPath in because I can't currently define the difference between `<execute>` when it follows `<initialise>` instead of when its found at any other level. Used XPath before when using Selenium with Python so hopefully I can figure that out.

Comment: @marksweb: I think the XPath `sibling` axis could solve that problem.

Comment: I haven't heard about that - I was trying to see if you could check up the tree for initialise, but if you can go down like that it might work if I check for `execute` as a sibling of `initialise`. Thanks